# Cookbook in runlist does not see overriden value of attribute

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, cookbook

I have several cookbooks in a runlist 'wrapper' cookbook. On one of the coobooks, I override the value of a node attribute, and then I restore it back after I do run some methods. When the next cookbook in the rulist runs, it does not see the restored value.

On the first cookbook in the runlist, I do node.override['my_attribute'] = 'new_value'.
I run some commands, and then I do node.override['my_attribute'] = 'original_value'.
When the next cookbook in the runlist runs, it still sees that node['my_attribute'] = 'new_value'.

How can I make sure the second cookbook uses the restored value?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the compile/converge aspect of Chef client run. If you can add some context on what you are trying to achieve (commands, etc), and why it is required. It will be possible to provide suggestions (as answers).

Comment: just a quick tip : put your code in code samples to make it easier to read